# how to create icon/app grouper in android?

Tags: android

Hey guys i am kinda new to android so i would like to know how to create a app grouper application in android. the app should be grouped into different categories like media,games,utility  the app i want to create is something like  [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.LifeBoat.AppGrouper&hl=en).  hope you guys will come up with some sort of help to me.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You need to ask way more precise questions here. Code samples would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

**So, for that you have to first get the list of all installed apps into your device this can be achieved by following code**

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

**Now, Display this list into Custom Listview and onClick event of that list launch particular app.**